# Salesforce apex collaborationgroup/collaborationgroupmember relationship?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I'm trying to get a list of collaboration groups and their associated members.  I'm trying to do the following soql query but it does not recognise the CollaborationGroup.CollaborationGroupMembers relationship

```
List<CollaborationGroup> cgs = new List<CollaborationGroup>([Select OwnerId, Id, (select CollaborationGroupMember.MemberId from CollaborationGroup.CollaborationGroupMembers) From CollaborationGroup]);
```

Looking at the API, CollaborationGroupMembers has a CollaborationGroupId which is the ID of the associated CollaborationGroup, so the relationship should exist - can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Thanks

J

edit: I have figured this out the other way round (going from member to group (child to parent) rather than vice-versa) by doing the following:

```
List<CollaborationGroupMember> cgs = new List<CollaborationGroupMember>([select MemberId, CollaborationGroupMember.CollaborationGroup.OwnerId from CollaborationGroupMember where CollaborationGroupMember.CollaborationGroup.Name]);
```

However, I'd still like to know why I couldn't do it from parent to child as I was trying to in the first place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm), it's not having a relation from `CollabarationGroup` into `CollabarationGroupMember`. But as you have mentioned, it's having the relation in the otherway around, see [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupmember.htm). 
So if you need to collect members from a particular group you can try

```
SELECT MemberId FROM CollaborationGroupMember WHERE CollaborationGroupId='your_group_id'
```

or filter it from `CollaborationGroup.Name` as you are already doing.